Spacy installation fails on python 3.13
trying to install Spacy using pip install -U spacy, but getting the following error message:
C:\Windows\System32>pip install spacy
Collecting spacy
  Using cached spacy-3.8.2.tar.gz (1.3 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [94 lines of output]
      Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
      Collecting setuptools
        Using cached setuptools-75.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
  Collecting cython<3.0,>=0.25
    Using cached Cython-0.29.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
  Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
    Using cached cymem-2.0.8-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
    Using cached preshed-3.0.9-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=0.28.0
    Using cached murmurhash-1.0.10-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
  Collecting thinc<8.4.0,>=8.3.0
    Using cached thinc-8.3.2.tar.gz (193 kB)
    Installing build dependencies: started
    Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
    error: subprocess-exited-with-error

    pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
    exit code: 1

    [62 lines of output]
    Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version < "3.9"' don't match your environment
    Collecting setuptools
      Using cached setuptools-75.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.9 kB)
    Collecting cython<3.0,>=0.25
      Using cached Cython-0.29.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
    Collecting murmurhash<1.1.0,>=1.0.2
      Using cached murmurhash-1.0.10-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
    Collecting cymem<2.1.0,>=2.0.2
      Using cached cymem-2.0.8-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
    Collecting preshed<3.1.0,>=3.0.2
      Using cached preshed-3.0.9-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
    Collecting blis<1.1.0,>=1.0.0
      Using cached blis-1.0.1.tar.gz (3.6 MB)
      Installing build dependencies: started
      Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
      Getting requirements to build wheel: started
      Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
      Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
    Collecting numpy<2.1.0,>=2.0.0
      Using cached numpy-2.0.2-cp313-cp313-win_amd64.whl
    Using cached setuptools-75.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.2 MB)
    Using cached Cython-0.29.37-py2.py3-none-any.whl (989 kB)
    Building wheels for collected packages: blis
      Building wheel for blis (pyproject.toml): started
      Building wheel for blis (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
      error: subprocess-exited-with-error

      Building wheel for blis (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
      exit code: 1

      [24 lines of output]
      BLIS_COMPILER? None
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      copying blis\about.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      copying blis\benchmark.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      copying blis\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\common.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\conftest.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_dotv.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\test_gemm.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis\tests
      copying blis\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis\tests
      copying blis\cy.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      copying blis\py.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      copying blis\cy.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      copying blis\__init__.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-313\blis
      running build_ext
      Build options win32 msvc
      BUILD ARCH: x86_64
      {'!EXITCODE': '00000000', 'ACLOCAL_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\aclocal;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\aclocal', 'AGENT_BUILDDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1', 'AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTFILEPUBLISHERPLUGIN': 'true', 'AGENT_DISABLELOGPLUGIN_TESTRESULTLOGPLUGIN': 'false', 'AGENT_HOMEDIRECTORY': 'C:\\agents\\2.202.0', 'AGENT_ID': '92', 'AGENT_JOBNAME': 'JSONL Python38Windows', 'AGENT_JOBSTATUS': 'Succeeded', 'AGENT_LOGTOBLOBSTORAGESERVICE': 'true', 'AGENT_MACHINENAME': 'WIN-CU8INV6766V', 'AGENT_NAME': 'Hosted Agent', 'AGENT_OS': 'Windows_NT', 'AGENT_OSARCHITECTURE': 'X64', 'AGENT_READONLYVARIABLES': 'true', 'AGENT_RETAINDEFAULTENCODING': 'false', 'AGENT_ROOTDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a', 'AGENT_SERVEROMDIRECTORY': 'C:\\agents\\2.202.0\\externals\\vstsom', 'AGENT_TASKRESTRICTIONSENFORCEMENTMODE': 'Enabled', 'AGENT_TEMPDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\_temp', 'AGENT_TOOLSDIRECTORY': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows', 'AGENT_USEWORKSPACEID': 'true', 'AGENT_VERSION': '2.202.0', 'AGENT_WORKFOLDER': 'D:\\a', 'ALLUSERSPROFILE': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'ANDROID_HOME': 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk', 'ANDROID_NDK_HOME': 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle', 'ANDROID_NDK_LATEST_HOME': 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk\\ndk\\23.1.7779620', 'ANDROID_NDK_PATH': 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle', 'ANDROID_NDK_ROOT': 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk\\ndk-bundle', 'ANDROID_SDK_ROOT': 'C:\\Android\\android-sdk', 'ANT_HOME': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\ant\\tools\\apache-ant-1.10.12', 'APPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\AppData\\Roaming', 'AR': 'llvm-ar', 'AS': 'llvm-as', 'AZURE_EXTENSION_DIR': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\AzureCliExtensionDirectory', 'AZURE_HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'VSTS_116cc368-5c0c-4eb4-bb44-7f3fa5bdce14_build_6_0', 'BUILD_ARTIFACTSTAGINGDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\a', 'BUILD_BINARIESDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\b', 'BUILD_BUILDID': '17021', 'BUILD_BUILDNUMBER': '20220408.7', 'BUILD_BUILDURI': 'vstfs:///Build/Build/17021', 'BUILD_CONTAINERID': '11809685', 'BUILD_DEFINITIONNAME': 'explosion.cython-blis', 'BUILD_DEFINITIONVERSION': '1', 'BUILD_QUEUEDBY': 'GitHub', 'BUILD_QUEUEDBYID': '38e7e9f7-fc06-4f5a-b6dd-1782f4ef7c25', 'BUILD_REASON': 'PullRequest', 'BUILD_REPOSITORY_GIT_SUBMODULECHECKOUT': 'False', 'BUILD_REPOSITORY_ID': 'explosion/cython-blis', 'BUILD_REPOSITORY_LOCALPATH': 'D:\\a\\1\\s', 'BUILD_REPOSITORY_NAME': 'explosion/cython-blis', 'BUILD_REPOSITORY_PROVIDER': 'GitHub', 'BUILD_REPOSITORY_URI': 'https://github.com/explosion/cython-blis', 'BUILD_REQUESTEDFOR': 'GitHub', 'BUILD_REQUESTEDFOREMAIL': '', 'BUILD_REQUESTEDFORID': '38e7e9f7-fc06-4f5a-b6dd-1782f4ef7c25', 'BUILD_SOURCEBRANCH': 'refs/pull/69/merge', 'BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME': 'merge', 'BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\s', 'BUILD_SOURCEVERSION': '273ec162fa5f042b5d946638cedd954583ff8111', 'BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONAUTHOR': 'Daniël de Kok', 'BUILD_SOURCEVERSIONMESSAGE': 'Merge 1de7a1931422b892af086ce69604e7e3459e9f8e into 6daabf0c925bfe67f7d87874ce014eb3212711e7', 'BUILD_STAGINGDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\a', 'CABAL_DIR': 'C:\\cabal', 'CC': 'clang', 'COBERTURA_HOME': 'C:\\cobertura-2.1.1', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'COMMON_TESTRESULTSDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\TestResults', 'COMPUTERNAME': 'WIN-CU8INV6766V', 'COMSPEC': 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe', 'CONDA': 'C:\\Miniconda', 'CONFIG_SITE': 'C:/Program Files/Git/etc/config.site', 'CHOCOLATEYINSTALL': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey', 'CHROMEWEBDRIVER': 'C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\ChromeDriver', 'COMMONPROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Common Files', 'COMMONPROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files\\Common Files', 'DISPLAY': 'needs-to-be-defined', 'DOTNET_MULTILEVEL_LOOKUP': '0', 'DRIVERDATA': 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\Drivers\\DriverData', 'EXEPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\bin', 'EDGEWEBDRIVER': 'C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\EdgeDriver', 'GCM_INTERACTIVE': 'Never', 'GHCUP_INSTALL_BASE_PREFIX': 'C:\\', 'GHCUP_MSYS2': 'C:\\msys64', 'GIT_TERMINAL_PROMPT': '0', 'GOROOT_1_15_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\go\\1.15.15\\x64', 'GOROOT_1_16_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\go\\1.16.15\\x64', 'GOROOT_1_17_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\go\\1.17.8\\x64', 'GOROOT_1_18_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\go\\1.18.0\\x64', 'GRADLE_HOME': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\gradle\\tools\\gradle-7.4', 'GECKOWEBDRIVER': 'C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\GeckoDriver', 'HOME': 'C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator', 'HOMEDRIVE': 'C:', 'HOMEPATH': '\\Users\\VssAdministrator', 'HOSTNAME': 'WIN-CU8INV6766V', 'IEWEBDRIVER': 'C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\IEDriver', 'IMAGENAME': 'windows-latest', 'INFOPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\info;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\info;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\info;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\share\\info', 'IMAGEOS': 'win22', 'IMAGEVERSION': '20220330.1', 'JAVA_HOME': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\\8.0.322-6\\x64', 'JAVA_HOME_11_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\\11.0.14-101\\x64', 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\\17.0.2-8\\x64', 'JAVA_HOME_8_X64': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\\8.0.322-6\\x64', 'LANG': 'en_US.UTF-8', 'LOCALAPPDATA': 'C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\AppData\\Local', 'LOGONSERVER': '\\\\WIN-CU8INV6766V', 'M2': 'C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\maven\\apache-maven-3.8.5\\bin', 'M2_REPO': 'C:\\ProgramData\\m2', 'MANPATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\local\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\share\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\man;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\share\\man', 'MAVEN_OPTS': '-Xms256m', 'MINGW_CHOST': 'x86_64-w64-mingw32', 'MINGW_PACKAGE_PREFIX': 'mingw-w64-x86_64', 'MINGW_PREFIX': 'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64', 'MSDEPLOY_HTTP_USER_AGENT': 'VSTS_116cc368-5c0c-4eb4-bb44-7f3fa5bdce14_build_6_0', 'MSYSTEM': 'MINGW64', 'MSYSTEM_CARCH': 'x86_64', 'MSYSTEM_CHOST': 'x86_64-w64-mingw32', 'MSYSTEM_PREFIX': 'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64', 'MONAGENTCLIENTLOCATION': 'C:\\Packages\\Plugins\\Microsoft.Azure.Geneva.GenevaMonitoring\\2.35.0.2\\Monitoring\\Agent', 'NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS': '4', 'OLDPWD': 'D:/a/1/s', 'ORIGINAL_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.8.10\\x64\\Scripts;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.8.10\\x64;C:\\agents\\2.202.0\\externals\\git\\cmd;C:\\agents\\2.202.0\\externals\\git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\5.0\\bin;C:\\aliyun-cli;C:\\vcpkg;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NSIS;C:\\tools\\zstd;C:\\Program Files\\Mercurial;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\stack\\2.7.5\\x64;C:\\cabal\\bin;C:\\ghcup\\bin;C:\\tools\\ghc-9.2.2\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\mysql\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\GeckoDriver;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sbt\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GitHub CLI;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pipx_bin;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\go\\1.16.15\\x64\\bin;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.9.12\\x64\\Scripts;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.9.12\\x64;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Ruby\\3.0.3\\x64\\bin;C:\\tools\\kotlinc\\bin;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\\8.0.322-6\\x64\\bin;C:\\npm\\prefix;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\ProgramData\\kind;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\ProgramData\\Chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Docker;C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Web Platform Installer;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\site\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\pulumi\\tools\\Pulumi\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\maven\\apache-maven-3.8.5\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Service Fabric\\bin\\Fabric\\Fabric.Code;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Service Fabric\\Tools\\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\GitHub CLI;C:\\tools\\php;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sbt\\bin;C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\ChromeDriver;C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\EdgeDriver;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSCLIV2;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\SessionManagerPlugin\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSSAMCLI\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\.cargo\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps', 'ORIGINAL_TEMP': 'C:/Users/VSSADM~1/AppData/Local/Temp', 'ORIGINAL_TMP': 'C:/Users/VSSADM~1/AppData/Local/Temp', 'OS': 'windows', 'PATH': 'C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\local\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python38\\Scripts;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.8.10\\x64\\Scripts;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.8.10\\x64;C:\\agents\\2.202.0\\externals\\git\\cmd;C:\\agents\\2.202.0\\externals\\git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\MongoDB\\Server\\5.0\\bin;C:\\aliyun-cli;C:\\vcpkg;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\NSIS;C:\\tools\\zstd;C:\\Program Files\\Mercurial;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\stack\\2.7.5\\x64;C:\\cabal\\bin;C:\\ghcup\\bin;C:\\tools\\ghc-9.2.2\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\mysql\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.1.3\\bin\\x64;C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\GeckoDriver;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sbt\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\GitHub CLI;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pipx_bin;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\go\\1.16.15\\x64\\bin;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.9.12\\x64\\Scripts;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.9.12\\x64;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Ruby\\3.0.3\\x64\\bin;C:\\tools\\kotlinc\\bin;C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Java_Temurin-Hotspot_jdk\\8.0.322-6\\x64\\bin;C:\\npm\\prefix;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft SDKs\\Azure\\CLI2\\wbin;C:\\ProgramData\\kind;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\\bin;C:\\Windows\\system32;C:\\Windows;C:\\Windows\\System32\\Wbem;C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0;C:\\Windows\\System32\\OpenSSH;C:\\Program Files\\dotnet;C:\\ProgramData\\Chocolatey\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Docker;C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft\\Web Platform Installer;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\Client SDK\\ODBC\\170\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\150\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\nodejs;C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSL\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\c\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\site\\bin;C:\\Strawberry\\perl\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\pulumi\\tools\\Pulumi\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\TortoiseSVN\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\CMake\\bin;C:\\ProgramData\\chocolatey\\lib\\maven\\apache-maven-3.8.5\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Service Fabric\\bin\\Fabric\\Fabric.Code;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Service Fabric\\Tools\\ServiceFabricLocalClusterManager;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\cmd;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\GitHub CLI;C:\\tools\\php;C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sbt\\bin;C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\ChromeDriver;C:\\SeleniumWebDrivers\\EdgeDriver;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSCLIV2;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\SessionManagerPlugin\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Amazon\\AWSSAMCLI\\bin;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\Binn;C:\\Program Files\\LLVM\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\.dotnet\\tools;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\.cargo\\bin;C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\vendor_perl;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\core_perl', 'PATHEXT': '.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.CPL', 'PGBIN': 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin', 'PGDATA': 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\data', 'PGPASSWORD': 'root', 'PGROOT': 'C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14', 'PGUSER': 'postgres', 'PHPROOT': 'c:\\tools\\php', 'PIPELINE_WORKSPACE': 'D:\\a\\1', 'PIPX_BIN_DIR': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pipx_bin', 'PIPX_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\pipx', 'PKG_CONFIG_PATH': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\lib\\pkgconfig;C:\\Program Files\\Git\\mingw64\\share\\pkgconfig', 'PLINK_PROTOCOL': 'ssh', 'POWERSHELL_DISTRIBUTION_CHANNEL': 'Azure-DevOps-win22', 'POWERSHELL_UPDATECHECK': 'Off', 'PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE': 'AMD64', 'PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER': 'Intel64 Family 6 Model 79 Stepping 1, GenuineIntel', 'PROCESSOR_LEVEL': '6', 'PROCESSOR_REVISION': '4f01', 'PROGRAMFILES': 'C:\\Program Files', 'PROMPT': '$P$G', 'PSEXECUTIONPOLICYPREFERENCE': 'Unrestricted', 'PSMODULEPATH': 'C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\\\Modules\\azurerm_2.1.0;C:\\\\Modules\\azure_2.1.0;C:\\Users\\packer\\Documents\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\WindowsPowerShell\\Modules;C:\\Windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\Modules;C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SQL Server\\130\\Tools\\PowerShell\\Modules\\', 'PUBLIC': 'C:\\Users\\Public', 'PWD': 'D:/a/1/s/flame-blis', 'PYTHON_VERSION': '3.8', 'PROGRAMDATA': 'C:\\ProgramData', 'PROGRAMFILES(X86)': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)', 'PROGRAMW6432': 'C:\\Program Files', 'RANLIB': 'echo', 'RESOURCES_TRIGGERINGALIAS': '', 'RESOURCES_TRIGGERINGCATEGORY': '', 'RTOOLS40_HOME': 'C:\\rtools40', 'RUNNER_TOOLSDIRECTORY': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows', 'SBT_HOME': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\sbt\\', 'SELENIUM_JAR_PATH': 'C:\\selenium\\selenium-server.jar', 'SHELL': 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\bash.exe', 'SHLVL': '2', 'SSH_ASKPASS': 'C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/git-askpass.exe', 'SYSTEM': 'build', 'SYSTEMDRIVE': 'C:', 'SYSTEMROOT': 'C:\\Windows', 'SYSTEM_ARTIFACTSDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\a', 'SYSTEM_COLLECTIONID': '116cc368-5c0c-4eb4-bb44-7f3fa5bdce14', 'SYSTEM_COLLECTIONURI': 'https://dev.azure.com/explosion-ai/', 'SYSTEM_CULTURE': 'en-US', 'SYSTEM_DEBUG': 'false', 'SYSTEM_DEFAULTWORKINGDIRECTORY': 'D:\\a\\1\\s', 'SYSTEM_DEFINITIONID': '6', 'SYSTEM_DEFINITIONNAME': 'explosion.cython-blis', 'SYSTEM_ENABLEACCESSTOKEN': 'SecretVariable', 'SYSTEM_HOSTTYPE': 'build', 'SYSTEM_ISSCHEDULED': 'False', 'SYSTEM_JOBATTEMPT': '1', 'SYSTEM_JOBDISPLAYNAME': 'JSONL Python38Windows', 'SYSTEM_JOBID': 'efb31c5a-ec83-5597-c79c-3c04d0eba6be', 'SYSTEM_JOBIDENTIFIER': 'JSONL.Python38Windows', 'SYSTEM_JOBNAME': 'Python38Windows', 'SYSTEM_JOBPARALLELISMTAG': 'Public', 'SYSTEM_JOBPOSITIONINPHASE': '1', 'SYSTEM_JOBTIMEOUT': '60', 'SYSTEM_PARALLELEXECUTIONTYPE': 'MultiConfiguration', 'SYSTEM_PHASEATTEMPT': '1', 'SYSTEM_PHASEDISPLAYNAME': 'JSONL', 'SYSTEM_PHASEID': 'ecb95708-c2a5-5456-f379-96cd8090c2a6', 'SYSTEM_PHASENAME': 'JSONL', 'SYSTEM_PIPELINESTARTTIME': '2022-04-08 12:45:25+00:00', 'SYSTEM_PLANID': '4bcc5172-4f8e-4a4f-b00f-1b3d5e2fe9dd', 'SYSTEM_POSTLINESSPEED': '10000', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_ISFORK': 'True', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_MERGEDAT': '', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTID': '899994381', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_PULLREQUESTNUMBER': '69', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEBRANCH': 'update-to-blis-0.9.0', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCECOMMITID': '1de7a1931422b892af086ce69604e7e3459e9f8e', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_SOURCEREPOSITORYURI': 'https://github.com/explosion/cython-blis', 'SYSTEM_PULLREQUEST_TARGETBRANCH': 'master', 'SYSTEM_RESTRICTSECRETS': 'True', 'SYSTEM_SERVERTYPE': 'Hosted', 'SYSTEM_STAGEATTEMPT': '1', 'SYSTEM_STAGEDISPLAYNAME': '__default', 'SYSTEM_STAGEID': '96ac2280-8cb4-5df5-99de-dd2da759617d', 'SYSTEM_STAGENAME': '__default', 'SYSTEM_TASKDEFINITIONSURI': 'https://dev.azure.com/explosion-ai/', 'SYSTEM_TASKDISPLAYNAME': 'Generate JSONL (Windows)', 'SYSTEM_TASKINSTANCEID': '4bae54ba-656f-5414-04c0-0cf207e9f5bd', 'SYSTEM_TASKINSTANCENAME': 'CmdLine5', 'SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONCOLLECTIONURI': 'https://dev.azure.com/explosion-ai/', 'SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI': 'https://dev.azure.com/explosion-ai/', 'SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECT': 'Public', 'SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID': '5c6613e9-6ccf-48bd-81de-dbc3b0a6f957', 'SYSTEM_TIMELINEID': '4bcc5172-4f8e-4a4f-b00f-1b3d5e2fe9dd', 'SYSTEM_TOTALJOBSINPHASE': '1', 'SYSTEM_WORKFOLDER': 'D:\\a', 'TASK_DISPLAYNAME': 'Generate JSONL (Windows)', 'TASK_SKIPTRANSLATORFORCHECKOUT': 'False', 'TEMP': 'C:\\Users\\VSSADM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'TERM': 'xterm-256color', 'TF_BUILD': 'True', 'TMP': 'C:\\Users\\VSSADM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'TMPDIR': 'C:\\Users\\VSSADM~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp', 'USEPYTHONVERSION_PYTHONLOCATION': 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\Python\\3.8.10\\x64', 'USERDOMAIN': 'WIN-CU8INV6766V', 'USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE': 'WIN-CU8INV6766V', 'USERNAME': 'VssAdministrator', 'USERPROFILE': 'C:\\Users\\VssAdministrator', 'VCPKG_INSTALLATION_ROOT': 'C:\\vcpkg', 'VSTS_AGENT_PERFLOG': 'C:\\agents\\perflog', 'VSTS_PROCESS_LOOKUP_ID': 'vsts_175962b3-f397-42b7-b557-a072c6b9de45', 'VSTS_SECRET_VARIABLES': '', 'WINDIR': 'C:\\Windows', 'WIX': 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\WiX Toolset v3.11\\', '_': 'C:/hostedtoolcache/windows/Python/3.8.10/x64/python', 'AGENT.JOBSTATUS': 'Succeeded', 'NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX': 'C:\\npm\\prefix'}
      [COMMAND] C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin\clang.exe -c C:\Users\mhrja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pmdjlq7q\blis_b5ae1b1b42144361a74d256b23aa4662\blis\_src\config\bulldozer\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.c -o C:\Users\mhrja\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpjk9iuhzc\bli_cntx_init_bulldozer.o -O2 -std=c99 -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L -DBLIS_VERSION_STRING="0.9.0" -DBLIS_IS_BUILDING_LIBRARY -Iinclude\windows-x86_64 -I.\frame\3\ -I.\frame\1m\ -I.\frame\1f\ -I.\frame\1\ -I.\frame\include -IC:\Users\mhrja\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-pmdjlq7q\blis_b5ae1b1b42144361a74d256b23aa4662\blis\_src\include\windows-x86_64
      error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for blis
    Failed to build blis
    ERROR: ERROR: Failed to build installable wheels for some pyproject.toml based projects (blis)
    [end of output]

    note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1

  See above for output.

      note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

How to resolve it?

Just downgrade your python version.that should solve the issue.

The following wheels are available for the 3.8.2 version:
https://pypi.org/project/spacy/#files
It looks to me like you're using Python 3.13, which I haven't added to our build system yet.
You should probably install with --only-binary. It's difficult for us to ensure that compilation works well across platforms, and ultimately it requires some system dependencies (e.g. the right compiler toolchain). If you use --only-binary it will fall back to versions that are available by wheel, or fail --- in this case I expect it'll fail because there's no suitable wheels.

I had the same issue with python3.13. I downgraded to python 3.12.6 and proceed wirh spacy install  via pip inside a virtualenv and it worked. I guess not all library dependencies work in python 3.13

I had the same issue on python 3.13 on Windows.
I had to do the following on Windows:
install python 3.12. Since I use choco, I installed it as (see
https://community.chocolatey.org/packages/python312) :
choco install python312

As of this date, the installed version is 3.12.6
Next, I created a virtual environment in my project directory. Since my python installation was at c:\python312, the command looks like
 C:\python312\python.exe -m venv myenv

Activate the virtual environment (I am still in my project directory):
.\myenv\Scripts\activate

Upgraded pip (from within the virtual environment) just in case
python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Next - installed the packages that include spacy. The packages were installed successfully.
pip install -r requirements.txt

Note that I also needed to run the following:
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

My requirements.txt is:
python-dotenv==0.21.0
logging
extract-msg
pymongo
openai
nltk
spacy
numpy
pandas
scipy

